# Visualize hoisting throughout animation

Tags: javascript

I am planning on creating an animated series regarding explain javascript program. I believe that everything is better explained by animation, and words should complement those movements. Words should explain what animation does. Throughout my development career, I have read a lot of papers and watched lessons on the topic of "understanding core of javascript". Some of them were dull with plain text and recycled code from a different place, but I always 'get the idea' when I see the picture. No matter how explanation with text was boring, they manage to recoup it with pictures.
Anyway, I want to present you my first animation on Javascript program.

Here is the animation on [giphy](https://media.giphy.com/media/QfnOYnk8MtkZdPRQlr/giphy.gif) and if you want to pause the animation at any time, you can [view it here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdXUn.jpg)

**Why am I posting this here?**

Basically, I want to test the water with the view and mechanics of animation before I make more of them. In short, I need **opinions** on it. Good or bad, as long as they are constructive, I am fine with that.

**Where is this series going to be hosted?**

I want to create a repository on GitHub and host the animations with explanations in there. As soon as I get some feedback on this project, I will create a repository and start working on it.
​

Comment: While I really like the idea of explaining JS with animations,  opinion is off-topic on SO as ir does not fit into the Q&A format. I'm sorry :(

Comment: Oh, when I read "animate hoisting", I feared you would animate the "movement of declarations to the top". I was positively surprised! However, I wouldn't say "search for …" but just "do … in order"

Comment: @JonasWilms Oh ok. So, I can't place this kind of request for a feedback here on SO, can you tell me where can I? I don't want to spam in different places, so I would appreciate the guidance.

Comment: @Bergi Can I take a "positively surprised" to be a green light to produce more? Also, you would tell "Do function declarations in order" and "Do variable declarations in order" instead of what I have written, right?